# Explode ou Similar não quebrar delimitadores enclausurados

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um parser de CSS, mas quando chega num bloco assim:

```
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7");
    display: block;
```

Primeiro tenho que normalizar com:

```
$rules = str_replace(array("\n","\r"), array('',''), $rules);

// Que me retorna:
// height: 100%; background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"); display: block;
```

(pois os arquivos podem vir com as regras na mesma linha)

E ao aplicar:

```
$rules = explode(';',$rules);
```

o explode quebra no `;` dentro da string "...gif`;`base64..."

Consegui "solucionar" aplicando str_replace de `;base64` para `-base64` e depois na hora de renderizar o css, substituo de `-base64` para `;base64`. *Gambiarra level 9000*

Isso obviamente limita para apenas essa situação, e preciso de uma solução mais ampla, como não quebrar se o `;` estiver dentro de `"`, `'`, `(` ou `)`

Já tentei com `str_getcsv` e não funciona...

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PUtBJ9bm) da função completa.

Comment: Nesse caso, creio que você possa dar explode no `;\n`,

Comment: @GabrielTadraMainginski tenho que normalizar antes do explode e retirar todos os \r \n, pois as vezes o arquivo já vem com todas as regras numa linha só...

Comment: O [preg_split()](http://br2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) da o mesmo problema?

Comment: @perdeu Sim, o preg_split retorna exatamente a mesma coisa que o explode...

Comment: Os dados antes do ";" sempre serão de imagens? 
(jpg, gif, etc)

Comment: @Mukotoshi Atualmente apenas essa linha apresentou o problema, mas eu não sei se o cliente não vai utilizar outras linhas semelhantes no futuro.

Comment: Será que ajuda usando o indice? `$string = explode( "\n" , $css )` e use a linha `$string[1] // background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7");`, depois você consegue mais facil usando uma ER

Comment: @PapaCharlie A função é utilizada em vários arquivos diferentes com centenas de seletores CSS, alguns já minimizados e sem quebras de linhas entre as regras, não posso me basear na quebra de linha para separar as regras...

Comment: It's over 9000! Creio que no seu caso, compense não usar explode, mas sim fazer um pequeno parser. Sugeriria mudar o título da pergunta para "Como usar um Explode, **ou similar** para não quebrar delimitadores enclausurados", pois assim abre espaço para outras soluções.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui uma solução mais ampla usando uma REGEX que substitui todos os `;` que estiverem enclausurados dentro de `( )` por: `[ENCLOSED_DELIMITER]`, e após fazer a quebra com o `explode`, substitui de volta para `;`

```
$teste = 'height: 100px; background: url("data:image/gif;base64;//PRIMEIRO;"); display: block; background: url(\'data:image/gif;base64,//SEGUNDO\'); display: block; background: url(data:image/gif;base64,//TERCEIRO);';

$teste = preg_replace_callback(
            '/\([^\)]*\)/',
            function ($matches) {
                return str_replace(';', '[ENCLOSED_DELIMITER]', $matches[0]);
            },
            $teste);

$teste = explode(';', $teste);

foreach($teste as &$v) $v = str_replace('[ENCLOSED_DELIMITER]', ';', $v);

print_r(array_filter($teste));

// Retorno:

Array
(
    [0] => height: 100px
    [1] =>  background: url("data:image/gif;base64;//PRIMEIRO;")
    [2] =>  display: block
    [3] =>  background: url('data:image/gif;base64,//SEGUNDO')
    [4] =>  display: block
    [5] =>  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,//TERCEIRO)
)
```

Não deixa de ser uma gambiarra, mas pelo menos é mais ampla.

Se alguém souber de outras possibilidades que possam conter `;` nas regras CSS, por favor comente abaixo.

Segue o [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/b4uV2j75) do parser completo para quem tiver interesse.

Comment: heheeh.. agora ficou "Gambiarra level 9001"